# Toggling text and form action on button click with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

It's partially working, the button initially says 'add' and it goes to 'add.php' file but the button does not change text when clicked and it doesn't submit to the 'update.php' file - is the `'isAdd ? 'update.php' : 'add.php'` some kind of if statement? If so I don't think it's reading the isAdd variable properly... I've included my changed code and also the .js code that the button is controlled by underneath. Again, any (and I mean any) help on this is appreciated!

```
<form  method='post' class='myform'>
          <button id='insert'>Add</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        $('#insert').click(function () {
            var isAdd = this.value == 'Add';
                $(this).text(isAdd ? 'Cancel' : 'Add');
                $(this).closest('.myform').prop('action', isAdd ? 'update.php' : 'add.php');
                });
        </script>
    <script src='bookroom.js'></script>
    <p id='result'></p>
```

bookroom.js code:

```
$('.myform').submit(function(){
    return false;
});

$('#insert').click(function(){
    $.post(     
        $('.myform').prop('action'),
        $('.myform :input').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** or `prop()` to set form action and **[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to get the form. Also notice the use of `$(this)` instead of `$('#insert')`.

```
$('#insert').click(function () {
    var isAdd = $(this).text() == 'Add';
    $(this).text(isAdd ? 'Cancel' : 'Add');
    $(this).closest('form').attr('action', isAdd ? 'update.php' : 'add.php');
});
```

Comment: Partially working, though still avoiding any form action change, any chance of another look? :)

Comment: Updated the code. Also check https://jsfiddle.net/oL24k2Lt/5/ for testing. Also, I'd suggest add all code inside one click handler inside bookroom.js